# Best approach to model multiple children table database

Tags: database, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

What I have: A Postgres database with [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/).

What is the model: A main entity `Event` and many children inherited (10+). Each children will have attributes very different from each other. Each `Event` belong to an `User`, left out of the example as it is not important for this particular case. For a simplified example, I've attached a mock diagram.

[image: Model]

How do I use it: The model will be queried for the list of all aggregated events, in chronological order, and then filtered by its "type" in order to be displayed (`Parameter`, `Symptom`, ...). This means that I want a `list` with a subset of the most recent 20 `Event`s (as example). For each of those 20 I will get each individual data from the table (or embed it in the first place).
Some of the events will happen with an high frequency while others with a much lower frequency.

The question is, what would be the best approach to model this?
I came up with:

- Single table, `Event` contains everything

  - Cons: it will contains a lot of `NULL`s
  - Pros: everything can be aggregated through that table, no joins or views needed
- Multiple tables, one for each type

  - Cons: I will need to have lots of joins and views to aggregate the data
  - Pros: Each table and entry is meaningful of its data and type
- Multiple tables plus a main `Event` which points to the types row

  - Cons: Almost same as above but with an easier way to get certain aggregation per `User`
  - Pros: Same as above

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a straight-forward tree structure rooted at the User entity. Something like this:

[image]

You then just need a table for each entity:

- Users
- Events
- The Children (Parameter, Symptom, etc.)

The Events have a `user` field, that contains the ID of their parent User. Similarly, the Children have an `event` field that contains the ID of their parent Event.

Such that:

```
"Child" {
  event -> id of parent Event
}
Event {
  user -> id of parent User
}
```

In TS, you can create Entities for each type of Child (Symptom, Meal, etc.) so they remain strictly-typed. Having a seperate table for each allows you to optimize their DB representations however you want (indexing specific fields, normalizing, etc.). Seperate tables also allows you to avoid having a lot of NULLs for uncommon values.

Comment: Would this means the `child` table will have a lot of `NULL`s values as it is used to store all the different types of children?

Comment: @vabatta You're right; my original suggestion - of using a single normalized Child table - would cause excessive NULLs. I had assumed the Child Entities were fairly similar to one another, which is not the case here.

I've updated my answer to recommend seperate tables for each Child type.

Comment: Also, given the difference between the Child types and the relative simplicity of the Event type, you may consider a Document storage DB instead. MongoDB or AWS's DocumentDB, might be viable solutions.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. I was also considering a Document storage DB. I will update the question as soon as I finalise the solution.